# SQL - How to SUM and use WHERE clause on this SUM using 4 tables?

Tags: php, sql

So I need to build a tool wich sorts my customers on several parameters and then export it to CSV.
Everything's working fine except my SQL query (I've always been bad at it).

Here is my DB structure:

- Customers (id, CustomerLogin, CustomerNom, CustomerPrenom, CustomerReference)
- Orders (OrderId, OrderTotal)
- Products (ProductId, category)
- OrderProduct (CPId, OrderId, ProductId)

I need to sort my customers to build a mailing list (CustomerLogin is a mail address).
Filters I need to implement:

- Orders number
- Order**s** total
- Product Category

Here's my current query(using some php variables for total and categories):

```
SELECT C.id, C.CustomerReference, C.CustomerNom, C.CustomerPrenom, C.CustomerLogin, O.OrderTotal, O.OrderId  
FROM customers C  
JOIN orders O  
ON C.id = O.CustomerId  
JOIN OrderProduct OP  
ON O.OrderId = OP.OrderId  
JOIN products P  
ON OP.ProduitId = P.ProduitId  
WHERE O.OrderTotal >= $total  
AND P.category IN($product_categories);
```

So this returns me datas of every customer entry in the order table where these orders are filtered by total and product category.
For example:

```
C.Id, C.ref, C.nom, C.prenom, C.login, O.OrderTotal, O.Id  
1 - REF1 - DOE - John - johndoe@gmail.com - 550 - 1  
1 - REF1 - DOE - John - johndoe@gmail.com - 150 - 4  
1 - REF1 - DOE - John - johndoe@gmail.com - 800 - 8  
5 - REF5 - BOND - James - jb@mi6.com - 007 - 25  
8 - REF8 - ANOTHER - Dude - adude@gmail.com - 50 - 12
```

What I'd like to get:

```
C.Id, C.ref, C.nom, C.prenom, C.login, OrdersTotal, OrderNumber  
1 - REF1 - DOE - John - johndoe@gmail.com - 1500 - 3  
5 - REF5 - BOND - James - jb@mi6.com - 007 - 1  
8 - REF8 - ANOTHER - Dude - adude@gmail.com - 50 - 1
```

Problem is I also need to filter OrdersTotal and OrderNumber, so how can I sum and display it in my "SELECT" and then filter it in the "WHERE"? Is that even possible? I thougt about using subqueries or other stuff but I'm pretty bad at it so I could use some help on this.

Sorry for that long question but I need to be precise on this!
Hope you guys will understand what I mean and be able to help me, thanks !

ps: I've translated my table and column names so you can understand, there might be some errors but it's working on my side.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to ***Surajit Biswas*** this is the solution:

```
SELECT * FROM(    
SELECT C.id, C.CustomerReference, C.CustomerNom, C.CustomerPrenom, C.CustomerLogin, SUM(O.OrderTotal) order_total, COUNT(O.CustomerId) nb_com  
FROM customers C  
JOIN orders O ON C.id = O.CustomerId  
JOIN OrderProduct OP ON O.OrderId = OP.OrderId  
JOIN products P ON OP.ProduitId = P.ProduitId  
WHERE P.category IN($product_categories)  
GROUP BY C.id, C.CustomerReference, C.CustomerNom, C.CustomerPrenom, C.CustomerLogin
)A WHERE A.order_total >= $total AND A.nb_com >= $nbcom
```

Everything's working fine!
All credits @Surajit Biswas.

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY`. Combine with `SUM()` aggregate function!

Comment: Thanks for the GROUP BY, it will help me summing orders for each customer! I was also thinking about the COUNT() function for OrderNumber... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have used something kind of this:

```
SELECT OrderID, sum(Quantity) as sumquantity
FROM OrderDetails
group by OrderID
```

When my table structure is like:

```
OrderDetailID   OrderID ProductID   Quantity
1   10248   11  12
2   10248   42  10
3   10248   72  5
4   10249   14  9
5   10249   51  40
6   10250   41  10
7   10250   51  35
```

It gives me the output as:

```
ord_id  sumquantity
10248   27
10249   49
10250   60
10251   41
```

In fact at your case also it is easy...

```
SELECT C.id, C.CustomerReference, C.CustomerNom, C.CustomerPrenom, C.CustomerLogin,
      SUM(O.OrderTotal) order_total
FROM customers C  
  JOIN orders O  ON C.id = O.CustomerId  
  JOIN OrderProduct OP ON O.OrderId = OP.OrderId  
  JOIN products P ON OP.ProduitId = P.ProduitId
WHERE O.OrderTotal >= $total  
  AND P.category IN($product_categories)
GROUP BY C.id, C.CustomerReference, C.CustomerNom, C.CustomerPrenom, C.CustomerLogin
```

Comment: I can't really change my db structure because it's an already existing db with a lot of entries (about 20k customers, 50k orders and 3k products).
And to be honest I don't understand your structure :p

Comment: I am not at all asking you to change db structure....you can just get the concept , what I meant

Comment: @Pier, Can you please try like this :

`SELECT C.id, C.CustomerReference, C.CustomerNom, C.CustomerPrenom, C.CustomerLogin, SUM(O.OrderTotal) order_total FROM customers C

JOIN orders O

ON C.id = O.CustomerId

JOIN OrderProduct OP

ON O.OrderId = OP.OrderId

JOIN products P

ON OP.ProduitId = P.ProduitId WHERE O.OrderTotal >= $total

AND P.category IN($product_categories)  GROUP BY C.id, C.CustomerReference, C.CustomerNom, C.CustomerPrenom, C.CustomerLogin`

If it helps you, please accept my answer as "Helpful"

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your detailled query, I'll test it right now.

Comment: So, I tried and it seems like globally working !
But I need to filter on all orders total, for now it filters on ONE order total:
WHERE O.OrderTotal >= $total.
I'll try this: WHERE order_total >= $total

edit: WHERE order_total >= $total isn't working, I also tried WHERE (SUM(O.OrderTotal)) >= $total

Comment: Ha ha ha :) You have yet not chosen my answer as helpful...NP, I am experienced with that....anyways, see "order_total" is the name that we kept...it does not recognize "order_total"....to do that you have to write as
`Select * from (...here my previous entire select command...) A where A.order_total > = $total`

Comment: Sorry bro, I clicked on the arrow but it seems i'm not experienced enough for it to be displayed ;)
I'll try your answer after lunch break and keep you informed!
Thanks again (can't do more).

Comment: not the up arrow , there is a tick option  exactly at the starting left of my answer...ok , good luck

Comment: Ok, I checked your answer ;)
In order to keep the comment area clean, is there a way I can contact you directly?

Comment: Better say "no" next time :p
So, what you're telling me is to do something like that:
Select * from (full sql query) A where A.order_total >= $total ?

Comment: Allright it's working !
A huge thanks to you! Now I'll figure myself how to count orders and use the same method to filter it (WHERE A.order_total >= $montant AND A.order_number >= $orderNumber).